# Wrap UITextView text with background color Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview

Im trying to create custom text fields for my users.

Here is the result I want :

[image]

I need :

- The background color wrap the text with some padding
- Multiline
- Rounded corners

What is the right approach to do this ?